# Cannot find module of flask app deployed under docker+nginx+uwsgi

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a project written in flask, with structure like:

```
-/
 |- src
   |- __init__.py
   |- main.py
   |- module_a
       |- __init__.py
       |- ...
       |- ...
   |- web
       |- __init__.py
       |- web.py
 |- Dockerfile
```

The file `main.py` calls entry function defined in `web/web.py`, and `web.py` calls business function defined in `module_a`. It works fine with command `python main.py`.

So I plan to deploy it under docker, Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6

COPY ./src/* /app/
```

Build and run the web app in docker, I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from web import run
  File "./web.py", line 5, in <module>
    import module_a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_a'
```

Why did uwsgi cannot find `module_a`? Did I miss something?

Comment: how do you import function defined in `module_a`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your COPY statement. I created a sample with your data

```
FROM alpine
COPY ./src/* /app/
RUN ls -alh /app
COPY ./src /app
RUN ls -alh /app
```

If you build you will see the output

```
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine
 ---> 7328f6f8b418
Step 2/5 : COPY ./src/* /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ad9fbfdc161d
Step 3/5 : RUN ls -alh /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4dcad7cf4fba
Step 4/5 : COPY ./src /app
 ---> d25b4dc34f82
Removing intermediate container 4bf0fc884332
Step 5/5 : RUN ls -alh /app
 ---> Running in 34401d92bf03
total 16
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root        4.0K Sep  1 16:46 .
drwxr-xr-x   26 root     root        4.0K Sep  1 16:46 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           0 Sep  1 16:44 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           0 Sep  1 16:44 main.py
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Sep  1 16:45 module_a
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Sep  1 16:45 web
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           0 Sep  1 16:45 web.py
```

When you use `./src/*` it will copy contents of those matches to the /app. So you will not get the files correctly. So you should be using `COPY ./src /app`